# mysql parent and child with level

Tags: mysql

I have table structure like

```
id | parent_id
----------
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    2
8    2
9    5
10   7
```

This table has unlimited parent child relation
I want the end result  as given below

```
id | parent_id | level
---------------------------
1     0          0
2     0          0
3     0          0
4     0          0
5     1          1
6     1          1
7     2          1
8     2          1
9     5          2
10    7          2
```

Can anybody help with suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following article:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

From: **The Nested Set Model**

To: **Finding the Depth of the Nodes**

You shall arrive at the complete solution :)